# Должны ли привязываемые поля компонента быть публичными?

Tags: angular2, visual-studio-code

В общем, поставил [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) и он мне начал подсвечивать приватные поля, которые я бинжу в html-разметке:

> Identifier '_paginator' refers to a private member of the
>   componentAngular

Тем не менее, все прекрасно компилируется и работает.

Наткнулся вот на этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34574732/4244707), где говорится, что ранее так делать было нельзя, но теперь это поведение весьма ожидаемо.

Собственно, вопрос:

1. Как все таки правильно? Иметь публичные поля или приватные?
2. Можно ли это предупреждение убрать в Visual Studio Code? Пытался найти настройку, но не нашел=(

Comment: свойства, используемые в шаблоне должны быть паблик

Comment: @overthesanity это какое-то соглашение? Просто, с приватом тоже работает, но миллион предупреждений.

Comment: это работает в JIT моде, потому что шаблон компилируется в браузере, где нет TypeScript, скомпилируйте в АОТ моде и получите ту же ошибку. Это никакое не соглашение, вы же знаете С# и знаете что `private` можно использовать только внутри класса

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @overthesanity напишите ответом.